# how to show agm-direction in a bootstrap modal?

Tags: angular, google-maps, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to show the direction on a pop-up modal; The agm-direction is working perfectly fine, but when I put into the modal-body, I have to zoom to see both points. Below is the code I tried.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
            <agm-direction [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination">
            </agm-direction>
</agm-map>
```

[This is how it looks on page:[image: This is how it looks on page:]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMLD5.png)

[But when I put this code in modal-body, it appears like this:[image: But when I put this code in modal-body, it appears like this:]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd5h5.png)

I have tried with setting zoom property and also `triggerResize()` as suggested [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470652/how-to-properly-display-google-maps-in-a-bootstrap-modal-angular-4). But still I am getting the same view on the modal pop-up.

Could you please guide me to get the proper view on a modal pop-up?